# Can i combine a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE query with an UPDATE ... RETURNING query Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 queries which I would like to combine into a single query using postgres, is this possible?

```
  SELECT id
    FROM table_name
   WHERE id in (ids)
ORDER BY (ids)
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE table_name
   SET id = id + 1
 WHERE id in (ids)
RETURNING *
```

Essentially, I want to select some rows where the id is a given ID and lock those rows. I then want to update those rows and receive the result, however I can see that I am effectively selecting the results twice, first time with the `SELECT` and second time with the `RETURNING` and wonder if this could be improved.

Comment: Before posting a question to ask if something can be done, one should try it for one's self. If a problem is encountered, then post the details of what was tried and the issue that was encountered. Unless there is additional processing between the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and the `UPDATE`, or between the `UPDATE` and the end of the transaction, that can't be handled in a single query, the `UPDATE` statement alone is sufficient. Don't add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can combine the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries into a single query using the `RETURNING` clause in PostgreSQL.

```
WITH selected_rows AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM table_name
    WHERE id IN (ids)
    ORDER BY id
    FOR UPDATE
)
UPDATE table_name
SET id = id + 1
FROM selected_rows
WHERE table_name.id = selected_rows.id
RETURNING *;
```